# Kotlin: How to return a value from a lambda to a parent function?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, lambda

How can I return `String(bytes)` to getPost function, so I can `println(getPost(123))` and it would print the value of String(bytes)?

```kotlin
fun getPost(id: Int) {
        Fuel.get("https://kitsu.io/api/edge/posts/$id")
            .response { request, response, result ->
                val(bytes, error) = result
                if(bytes != null) {
                    println(String(bytes)) 
                    //I want to return String(bytes)

                }
            }
       

    }
```

Comment: You cannot, without using a suspend function. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70178210/9473786) for some alternate approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API you're using is an asynchronous API, and it's callback-based. This means the lambda you have here is run asynchronously and may not have been run yet when your `getPost` function returns. It is therefore not possible to get its result when returning from `getPost`.

To handle this kind of cases in a synchronous-like approach while retaining the benefits of async execution, you could use `suspend` functions and Kotlin coroutines. There is an additional module for Fuel that you can use to do exactly that:
https://fuel.gitbook.io/documentation/support/fuel-coroutines